How do I remove a tub/shower/handheld control with no internal screw?
There doesn't appear to be a screw holding the handle on - how do I remove it? Is it using a compression type anchor? Not an Allen wrench fitting.
click to embiggen




What are you actually trying to disassemble and why? These handled are usually integral with their hose; sometimes the actual spray head can he unscrewed and replaced but mostly folks replace the whole thing

Looks like it should just pull off the splines at this point.  Could simply be some corrosion in there "gluing" the handle to the shaft.  Give it a couple gentle taps with a hammer/mallet in various directions to see if you can break it free?
